# MySQL group_concat(utf8) in union truncated to 1024/3

Tags: mysql, group-concat

**TLDR:** `group_concat(utf8 varchar) union itself` returns only `group_concat_max_len/3` ASCII characters as if the character length was fixed instead of variable.
The `group_concat` alone returns `group_concat_max_len` characters as expected.

**The problem**

I have a table `tabletest` with a column `data` defined as an `UTF8 varchar(2048)`.
There is only a single row in the table with 1050 ASCII characters in the column.

A `group_concat` over this table/column returns 1024 characters (equals `group_concat_max_len`), which is expected.

But an union of this `group_concat` with the same `group_concat` returns 341 characters (equals `group_concat_max_len / 3`).

*Why does this happen?*

According to [MySQL Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The result type is TEXT or BLOB unless group_concat_max_len is less than or equal to 512, in which case the result type is VARCHAR or VARBINARY.

And from [MySQL The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html):

> Similarly, you can regard a TEXT column as a VARCHAR column. BLOB and TEXT differ from VARBINARY and VARCHAR in the following ways:
>
> - For indexes on BLOB and TEXT columns, you must specify an index prefix length. For CHAR and VARCHAR, a prefix length is optional. See Section 8.3.4, “Column Indexes”.
> - BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values.

So the return type should be `TEXT` which is also variable-length and should support ASCII characters in utf8 as 1-byte wide.

**Relevant answers acknowledging the problem**

[MySQL Truncating of result when using Group_Concat and Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469474/mysql-truncating-of-result-when-using-group-concat-and-concat/37979180#37979180)

[Weird result for GROUP_CONCAT on subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083929/weird-result-for-group-concat-on-subquery/40086192#40086192)

**Possible culprit**

Again from [MySQL The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html):

> Only the first max_sort_length bytes of the column are used when sorting. The default value of max_sort_length is 1024

AFAIK `UNION` needs to sort rows before eliminating duplicates, so this seems to be a possible reason. But changing it by `set max_sort_length=2048;` did *not* change the returned character count.

The only workaround seems to be `SET group_concat_max_len = 1539;` or more. Just 1538 or less returns only 512 or less characters. Why this strange number?

**Complete example**

```
create database uniontest collate utf8_general_ci;
create table uniontest.tabletest (data varchar(2048));
insert into uniontest.tabletest select repeat('a',1050);
```

Simple select of the length of the 1050 characters:

```
select length(data) from uniontest.tabletest;
```

Outputs:

```
+--------------+
| length(data) |
+--------------+
|         1050 |
+--------------+
```

Group concat of the single line of 1050 characters (so no separators are added). In server configuration *group_concat_max_len=1024*

```
select length(group_concat(data separator ',')) from uniontest.tabletest;
```

Output is truncated as expected:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| length(group_concat(data separator ',')) |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                     1024 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Now union with itself (in attempt to prevent additional datatype conversions):

```
select length(data) from (
select group_concat(data separator ',') as data from uniontest.tabletest union 
select group_concat(data separator ',') as data from uniontest.tabletest) d;
```

Unexpected result (expecting 1024):

```
+--------------+
| length(data) |
+--------------+
|          341 |
+--------------+
```

Tested on MySQL 5.6 and 5.7.

**EDIT**

Found a bug report about `ORDER BY` instead of `UNION` [ORDER BY truncates GROUP_CONCAT result](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41090). It is reported Closed, maybe only the `ORDER BY` case was fixed?

Comment: Some other strange results: http://rextester.com/MQY49212