# Override MySql subquery size limit of 256 chars?

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I need to group concat a series of id's in a column name section_users, the problem is when using a subquery the size is limited to 256 chars.
Is there a way to override that limit ? Mine can go up to 500 chars.

```
    SELECT s.*, rs.ressource_record_id, rs.ressource_main_id, rpg.account_type,
                (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ressource_record_id ORDER BY ressource_record_id) FROM ressources_section WHERE ressources_section.section_id=s.id) AS section_users
                FROM sections s
                LEFT JOIN ressources_section rs ON rs.section_id=s.id
                LEFT JOIN ressources_department rd ON rd.department_id=s.department_id AND rd.ressource_main_id=900
                LEFT JOIN ressources_params_general rpg ON rpg.department_id=s.department_id AND rpg.ressource_record_id=rd.ressource_record_id
                WHERE s.active=1 AND s.department_id IN (2,4,8,9) AND (rs.ressource_main_id=900 OR rpg.account_type=1)
                GROUP BY s.id
                ORDER BY s.section_name
```

Comment: Set the `group_concat_max_length` variable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with using a subquery. It applies to all uses of `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: No, the group_concat_max_length is set to 1024 but subqueries are limited to 256 chars limit.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40086192/1491895) mentions that it's reduced to 1/3 when used in a subquery. So try increasing to 2000.

Comment: @Barmar You made my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same situation, using mysql 5.7. According to some tests on the system, MySQL limits the number of characters in the group concat to 1/4 of the defined size when the group concat is inside a subquery, but when the maximum length setting is above 2048 characters, MySQL starts to consider the value defined in the configuration. I couldn't find a more specific answer in the MySQL documentation.